# $||u||=3 ,||u+v||=4, ||u-v||=6 $ defines explicitly $||v||$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

V is an Euclidean vectorspace $u,v \in V$ $||u||=3 ,||u+v||=4, ||u-v||=6 $ defines explicitly $||v||$

My idea is the following:

i)$||u+v||=(u+v)^2=u^2+2uv+v^2 =4$

ii)$||u-v||=(u-v)^2=u^2-2uv+v^2 =6$

If I add i) and ii) I get that $2u^2+2v^2=10 \implies u^2+v^2=5$ and from the description of the exercise we know that $||u||=3 \implies u^2=9$ which means that $v^2=-4$ which seems to be a contradiction to me. Am I right? Is my calculation correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Umm, that should be $\lVert u+v \rVert^2 = (u+v) \cdot (u+v) = u \cdot u + 2 (u \cdot v) + v \cdot v = 16$ and similarly for $\lVert u-v \rVert^2$.  Anyway, it looks like you're well on the way to rediscovering the *parallelogram law* $\lVert u+v \rVert^2 + \lVert u-v \rVert^2 = 2 (\lVert u \rVert^2 + \lVert v \rVert^2)$ which holds in a real inner product space.

Comment: $\lVert u-v \rVert^2 = 9$ which means that $\lVert u+v \rVert^2 + \lVert u-v \rVert^2 =25 = 2 (\lVert u \rVert^2 + \lVert v \rVert^2)$ am I right? Is that correct that $||v||$ is not an integer?

Answer (score 1):

The identity you need is
$$
\|u+v\|^2 +\|u-v\|^2 = 2\|u\|^2 + 2 \|v\|^2.
$$
This is almost what you have shown. You should just put the $\|.\|$ and the scalar products to be perfectly correct.
$$
\|u+v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + 2\langle u,v\rangle +\|v\|^2.
$$